# F# SAFE template: How to add library to the server?

Tags: f#, paket, f#-giraffe

I am trying to learn to use the SAFE framework and have installed the [SAFE template](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/template-overview/).

I want to add some code to the server which interacts with a MySql DB, but nothing I have tried seems to result in VS2019 recognizing a reference to the [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) library.

I have tried both of

```
paket add MySql.Data -g Server
paket add MySql.Data
```

each time followed by

```
fake build
```

However, in VS2019, `The namespace or module 'MySql' is not defined`.

Incidentally, I also tried adding (to a separate instance of the template) the library via Nuget, and unsurprisingly it did not work.

So how am I supposed to add a library to the server? I thought the server was just a plain old dotnet core app. Is it not?

I should also mention that while I have dabbled with paket, I am not exactly a power user. So that might explain my problem.

Comment: You need to specify the project you want to add it to (`--project Server`, for example) so that the references is added to that project's `paket.references`. I'd suggest reading the [paket docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-add.html).

Comment: For anyone reading this, Charles has given the correct answer. Problem solved for me.